# show that sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

we have this:  $a_0=2$

$a_{n+1}=a_n+(1+\frac{a_n}{n})^{1/2}$

please I just need a hint or something, I've tried but nothing...

Comment: If $a_n$ goes to $L$, then....

Comment: Observe that $a_{n+1} \gt a_n + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

you have that

$$\forall n>0\;\; a_{n+1}=a_n +(1+\frac{a_n}{n})^\frac12$$

thus, if $(a_n)_n$ converges to $L$,

then you will get

$$L=L+(1+0)^\frac12=L+1$$

which is impossible and $(a_n)_n$ diverges.

$(a_n)_n$ is increasing $\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=+\infty$.